# What is the best way to delete files & folders in a directory excluding the contents of one folder?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I'm trying to automate some file house keeping I do pretty often. I want to delete all of the files and folders in a directory while excluding the folder "./xfer" and its contents.

I've bee trying to do it using the find command but it is turning out a bit clunky. Is there a better way? I set up my test environment by running:

```
mkdir test0{1..5}; find . -type d -exec touch '{}'/test-0{1..5} \;
```

Here is the command I've been working on. Btw I am somewhat new and am mostly doing this as a learning exercise. Also, this would be the last command of a small script I am almost done with.

```
find /some/directory/path/* -type f ! -path "/some/directory/path/xfer/*" -exec rm -fv {} \;; find /some/directory/path/*  -type d ! -path "/some/directory/path/xfer" -exec rm -rfv {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-prune`:

```
find . -path ./xfer -prune -o -exec rm -fv {} \;
```

When listing the files, if the path matches `./xfer` the file is pruned, otherwise `rm` is called.

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./* -prune ! -path './xfer' -exec rm -fr {} +
```

More correct (but GNU):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'xfer' -exec rm -fr {} +
```

or

```
find . ! -path './xfer' ! -path '.xfer/*' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a for loop?
`for i in $(ls|grep -v xfer);do rm -r $i;done`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you're looking for, but that's how I usually do it. I move the stuff I want to keep out of the way.

```
mv dir/keepme tmp/keepme
rm -rf dir/*
mv tmp/keepme dir/keepme
```

Careful to stay within the same filesystem so `mv` does not copy/delete.